Are Metal Roofs Not Cool Roofs?
We have recently moved into a 1920s Dutch Colonial (curvy roofline) with an older asphalt roof. We are pretty sure we want to replace it with metal, but we're still trying to decide between aluminum shingles (permalock) and steel or aluminum standing seam.
One of the things that is most important to us is temperature control. We live in hot-summer-cold-winter New England. The house currently has no insulation at all (we are about to add quite a lot), and it got SO hot this summer!
I tried to have a conversation about Solar Reflectance and Thermal Emittance with the metal tile salesperson, but he was poorly informed and pulled the number 92 from the back of his mind somewhere. He had rehearsed this unhelpful bit about wrapping the roof in aluminum foil "like a baked potato."
My question for you is: are aluminum (or steel) roofs reflective enough to prevent attic heating in the sunny summer? Would it still be necessary to choose a light color? Does none of this matter if we insulate the attic ceiling?
I understand that aluminum cools down quickly in the evening, but if they've allowed the attic wood to bake all day, would they not be considered "cool" roofs? I read conflicting answers online!


No insulation might also mean poor or no attic ventilation.  Attic ventilation helps keep the roof deck cooler, instead of just cooking all day.  Lighter colours like white can help also.  Shiny like bare aluminum might reflect the sunlight into your neighbours/cars.

Do you have a ridge vent?    That is very cheap to add and helps cool more than your choice of roof.

I can anecdotally comment that a dark-coloured metal roof can still get you a very hot roof space. It absorbs the light, gets hot, and passes some of that heat straight inside.

Thanks, we have great ventilation in that there are two double-hung windows at opposite ends and lots of gaps where you can see daylight down under the eaves. Bats even -- maybe too much ventilation! The roof company may add these little vent hut-like things.

Unpainted shiny metal is actually a poor reflector of heat, and a light-painted metal roof can be significantly cooler than an asphalt shingle roof per the US Department of Energy.  A metal roof manufacturer agrees, as well as a general roofing company, although they point out that there may be cooler options, such as wood shingles.
If you are looking for academic studies, I managed to find 3:

A Study of the Energy-Saving Potential of
Metal Roofs Incorporating
Dynamic Insulation Systems (ORNL)
The Thermal Performance of Painted
and Unpainted Standing-Seam
Metal Roofing Systems Exposed
to Two Years of Weathering (ORNL)
Comparative Summer Thermal Performance of Finished and Unfinished
Metal Roofing Products with Composition Shingles


Metal roofs are not "reflective" unless they're unpainted shiny metal.
My BBQ has a metal heat disperser thing that looks just like corrugated metal roofing, but heavier.
"Cat on a Hot Tin Roof" sez it all.
